# How can i get specific fileld from the Mongo DB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have written below code which is fetching 3 documents , from that document i want to display only specific filed excluding the other field

```
async function getFiled (client, IDs)
{
  for (var i=0; i<IDs.length; i++) {
    console.log ('the value is ' + IDs [i]);

    const cursor =client.db ('snapp_transactions').collection ('price_check_validation').find (
      {
        Scenario: IDs [i]
      }, {
        'Ticket Code': 0

      }
    );

    const result=await cursor.toArray ();
   
    console.log (result);
```

*The piece out put is as below - :*

```
{ _id: 6114ce6614796e5fbe316be4,
    App: 'PRO_WH_DS',
    'Other Voucher Code': '',
    'Date and Time Performed': '',
    'SnApp Error': '',
    Done: '',
    'Unit Tax Quoted': '$30.61',
    'AQ perDayNetPrice': '',
    'Gold "Upgrade Tax"': '',
    'Gold Source': '',
    'Execution Time': 2021-08-12T07:31:50.002Z,
    'SnApp API Tax Inclusive (Y/N)': '',
    'Voucher Bridging Amount (7800)': '',
    'SnApp Ticket Value': '',
    'SnApp Ticket Tax': '',
    'AQ netPrice': '',
    Status: 'Complete',
    'Execution Environment': 'STAGE',
    'Order ID': 'KJWT62312828’,
   'Ticket Code': '4LO0Z',}
```

After searching on certain blog i found to exclude any field i have to assigned that value to 0 , but after that also i am getting that field in my o/p .

Please assist where i am have to make correct ?

*Node Version -8.12 , MongoDb -3.12*

After running `npm list` these are the below library i got

```
│ │ │     └── path-is-absolute@1.0.1 deduped
│ │ ├── ncp@2.0.0
│ │ ├── npmlog@4.1.2 deduped
│ │ ├─┬ plist@3.0.1
│ │ │ ├── base64-js@1.3.0
│ │ │ ├── xmlbuilder@9.0.7 deduped
│ │ │ └── xmldom@0.1.27 deduped
│ │ ├── pngjs@3.4.0
│ │ ├── request@2.88.0 deduped
│ │ ├── request-promise@4.2.4 deduped
│ │ ├─┬ rimraf@2.6.3
│ │ │ └── glob@7.1.3 deduped
│ │ ├── semver@6.0.0 deduped
│ │ ├── source-map-support@0.5.12 deduped
│ │ ├── teen_process@1.14.1 deduped
│ │ ├─┬ which@1.3.1
│ │ │ └── isexe@2.0.0
│ │ └─┬ yauzl@2.10.0
│ │   ├── buffer-crc32@0.2.13 deduped
│ │   └─┬ fd-slicer@1.1.0
│ │     └── pend@1.2.0
│ ├─┬ appium-tizen-driver@1.1.1-beta.3
│ │ ├── @babel/runtime@7.4.4 deduped
│ │ ├── appium-base-driver@3.15.5 deduped
│ │ ├─┬ appium-sdb@1.0.0-beta
│ │ │ ├── appium-support@2.27.0 deduped
│ │ │ ├── asyncbox@2.5.2 deduped
│ │ │ ├─┬ babel-runtime@5.8.24
│ │ │ │ └── core-js@1.2.7
│ │ │ ├── bluebird@3.5.4 deduped
│ │ │ ├── lodash@3.10.1
│ │ │ ├─┬ source-map-support@0.4.18
│ │ │ │ └── source-map@0.5.7
│ │ │ └── teen_process@1.14.1 deduped
│ │ ├── appium-support@2.27.0 deduped
│ │ ├── asyncbox@2.5.2 deduped
│ │ ├── bluebird@3.5.4 deduped
│ │ ├── fancy-log@1.3.3 deduped
│ │ ├─┬ jimp@0.5.6
│ │ │ ├── @babel/polyfill@7.4.4 deduped
│ │ │ ├─┬ @jimp/custom@0.5.4
│ │ │ │ ├─┬ @jimp/core@0.5.4
│ │ │ │ │ ├─┬ @jimp/utils@0.5.0
│ │ │ │ │ │ └── core-js@2.6.5 deduped
│ │ │ │ │ ├── any-base@1.1.0 deduped
│ │ │ │ │ ├── buffer@5.2.1 deduped
│ │ │ │ │ ├── core-js@2.6.5 deduped
│ │ │ │ │ ├── exif-parser@0.1.12 deduped
│ │ │ │ │ ├── file-type@9.0.0 deduped
│ │ │ │ │ ├── load-bmfont@1.4.0 deduped
│ │ │ │ │ ├── mkdirp@0.5.1 deduped
│ │ │ │ │ ├── phin@2.9.3 deduped
│ │ │ │ │ ├── pixelmatch@4.0.2 deduped
│ │ │ │ │ └── tinycolor2@1.4.1 deduped
│ │ │ │ └── core-js@2.6.5 deduped
│ │ │ ├─┬ @jimp/plugins@0.5.5
│ │ │ │ ├─┬ @jimp/plugin-blit@0.5.4
│ │ │ │ │ ├── @jimp/utils@0.5.0 deduped
│ │ │ │ │ └── core-js@2.6.5 deduped
│ │ │ │ ├─┬ @jimp/plugin-blur@0.5.0
│ │ │ │ │ ├── @jimp/utils@0.5.0 deduped
│ │ │ │ │ └── core-js@2.6.5 deduped
│ │ │ │ ├─┬ @jimp/plugin-color@0.5.5
│ │ │ │ │ ├── @jimp/utils@0.5.0 deduped
│ │ │ │ │ ├── core-js@2.6.5 deduped
│ │ │ │ │ └── tinycolor2@1.4.1 deduped
│ │ │ │ ├─┬ @jimp/plugin-contain@0.5.4
│ │ │ │ │ ├── @jimp/utils@0.5.0 deduped
│ │ │ │ │ └── core-js@2.6.5 deduped
│ │ │ │ ├─┬ @jimp/plugin-cover@0.5.4
│ │ │ │ │ ├── @jimp/utils@0.5.0 deduped
│ │ │ │ │ └── core-js@2.6.5 deduped
│ │ │ │ ├─┬ @jimp/plugin-crop@0.5.4
│ │ │ │ │ ├── @jimp/utils@0.5.0 deduped
│ │ │ │ │ └── core-js@2.6.5 deduped
│ │ │ │ ├─┬ @jimp/plugin-displace@0.5.0
│ │ │ │ │ ├── @jimp/utils@0.5.0 deduped
│ │ │ │ │ └── core-js@2.6.5 deduped
│ │ │ │ ├─┬ @jimp/plugin-dither@0.5.0
│ │ │ │ │ ├── @jimp/utils@0.5.0 deduped
│ │ │ │ │ └── core-js@2.6.5 deduped
│ │ │ │ ├─┬ @jimp/plugin-flip@0.5.0
│ │ │ │ │ ├── @jimp/utils@0.5.0 deduped
│ │ │ │ │ └── core-js@2.6.5 deduped
│ │ │ │ ├─┬ @jimp/plugin-gaussian@0.5.0
│ │ │ │ │ ├── @jimp/utils@0.5.0 deduped
│ │ │ │ │ └── core-js@2.6.5 deduped
│ │ │ │ ├─┬ @jimp/plugin-invert@0.5.0
│ │ │ │ │ ├── @jimp/utils@0.5.0 deduped
│ │ │ │ │ └── core-js@2.6.5 deduped
│ │ │ │ ├─┬ @jimp/plugin-mask@0.5.4
│ │ │ │ │ ├── @jimp/utils@0.5.0 deduped
│ │ │ │ │ └── core-js@2.6.5 deduped
│ │ │ │ ├─┬ @jimp/plugin-normalize@0.5.4
│ │ │ │ │ ├── @jimp/utils@0.5.0 deduped
│ │ │ │ │ └── core-js@2.6.5 deduped
│ │ │ │ ├─┬ @jimp/plugin-print@0.5.4
│ │ │ │ │ ├── @jimp/utils@0.5.0 deduped
│ │ │ │ │ ├── core-js@2.6.5 deduped
│ │ │ │ │ └── load-bmfont@1.4.0 deduped
│ │ │ │ ├─┬ @jimp/plugin-resize@0.5.4
│ │ │ │ │ ├── @jimp/utils@0.5.0 deduped
│ │ │ │ │ └── core-js@2.6.5 deduped
│ │ │ │ ├─┬ @jimp/plugin-rotate@0.5.4
│ │ │ │ │ ├── @jimp/utils@0.5.0 deduped
│ │ │ │ │ └── core-js@2.6.5 deduped
│ │ │ │ ├─┬ @jimp/plugin-scale@0.5.0
│ │ │ │ │ ├── @jimp/utils@0.5.0 deduped
│ │ │ │ │ └── core-js@2.6.5 deduped
│ │ │ │ ├── core-js@2.6.5 deduped
│ │ │ │ └── timm@1.6.1 deduped
│ │ │ ├─┬ @jimp/types@0.5.4
│ │ │ │ ├─┬ @jimp/bmp@0.5.4
│ │ │ │ │ ├── @jimp/utils@0.5.0 deduped
│ │ │ │ │ ├── bmp-js@0.1.0 deduped
│ │ │ │ │ └── core-js@2.6.5 deduped
│ │ │ │ ├─┬ @jimp/gif@0.5.0
│ │ │ │ │ ├── @jimp/utils@0.5.0 deduped
│ │ │ │ │ ├── core-js@2.6.5 deduped
│ │ │ │ │ └── omggif@1.0.9 deduped
│ │ │ │ ├─┬ @jimp/jpeg@0.5.4
│ │ │ │ │ ├── @jimp/utils@0.5.0 deduped
│ │ │ │ │ ├── core-js@2.6.5 deduped
│ │ │ │ │ └── jpeg-js@0.3.5 deduped
│ │ │ │ ├─┬ @jimp/png@0.5.4
│ │ │ │ │ ├── @jimp/utils@0.5.0 deduped
│ │ │ │ │ ├── core-js@2.6.5 deduped
│ │ │ │ │ └── pngjs@3.4.0 deduped
│ │ │ │ ├─┬ @jimp/tiff@0.5.4
│ │ │ │ │ ├── core-js@2.6.5 deduped
│ │ │ │ │ └── utif@2.0.1 deduped
│ │ │ │ ├── core-js@2.6.5 deduped
│ │ │ │ └── timm@1.6.1 deduped
│ │ │ └── core-js@2.6.5 deduped
│ │ ├── lodash@4.17.11 deduped
│ │ ├── source-map-support@0.5.12 deduped
│ │ ├── teen_process@1.14.1 deduped
│ │ └─┬ yargs@12.0.5
│ │   ├── cliui@4.1.0 deduped
│ │   ├── decamelize@1.2.0 deduped
│ │   ├── find-up@3.0.0 deduped
│ │   ├── get-caller-file@1.0.3
│ │   ├── os-locale@3.1.0 deduped
│ │   ├── require-directory@2.1.1 deduped
│ │   ├── require-main-filename@1.0.1
│ │   ├── set-blocking@2.0.0 deduped
│ │   ├─┬ string-width@2.1.1
│ │   │ ├── is-fullwidth-code-point@2.0.0
│ │   │ └─┬ strip-ansi@4.0.0
│ │   │   └── ansi-regex@3.0.0
│ │   ├── which-module@2.0.0 deduped
│ │   ├── y18n@4.0.0 deduped
│ │   └─┬ yargs-parser@11.1.1
│ │     ├── camelcase@5.3.1 deduped
│ │     └── decamelize@1.2.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ appium-uiautomator2-driver@1.33.1
│ │ ├── @babel/runtime@7.4.4 deduped
│ │ ├── appium-adb@7.7.1 deduped
│ │ ├── appium-android-driver@4.15.1 deduped
│ │ ├── appium-base-driver@3.15.5 deduped
│ │ ├── appium-support@2.27.0 deduped
│ │ ├── appium-uiautomator2-server@3.5.1
│ │ ├── asyncbox@2.5.2 deduped
│ │ ├── bluebird@3.5.4 deduped
│ │ ├── lodash@4.17.11 deduped
│ │ ├── portscanner@2.2.0 deduped
│ │ ├── request@2.88.0 deduped
│ │ ├── request-promise@4.2.4 deduped
│ │ ├── source-map-support@0.5.12 deduped
│ │ ├── teen_process@1.14.1 deduped
│ │ └── yargs@13.2.2 deduped
│ ├─┬ appium-windows-driver@1.5.1
│ │ ├── @babel/runtime@7.4.4 deduped
│ │ ├── appium-base-driver@3.15.5 deduped
│ │ ├── appium-support@2.27.0 deduped
│ │ ├── asyncbox@2.5.2 deduped
│ │ ├── bluebird@3.5.4 deduped
│ │ ├── lodash@4.17.11 deduped
│ │ ├── request-promise@4.2.4 deduped
│ │ ├── source-map-support@0.5.12 deduped
│ │ ├── teen_process@1.14.1 deduped
│ │ └─┬ yargs@12.0.5
│ │   ├── cliui@4.1.0 deduped
│ │   ├── decamelize@1.2.0 deduped
│ │   ├── find-up@3.0.0 deduped
│ │   ├── get-caller-file@1.0.3
│ │   ├── os-locale@3.1.0 deduped
│ │   ├── require-directory@2.1.1 deduped
│ │   ├── require-main-filename@1.0.1
│ │   ├── set-blocking@2.0.0 deduped
│ │   ├─┬ string-width@2.1.1
│ │   │ ├── is-fullwidth-code-point@2.0.0
│ │   │ └─┬ strip-ansi@4.0.0
│ │   │   └── ansi-regex@3.0.0
│ │   ├── which-module@2.0.0 deduped
│ │   ├── y18n@4.0.0 deduped
│ │   └─┬ yargs-parser@11.1.1
│ │     ├── camelcase@5.3.1 deduped
│ │     └── decamelize@1.2.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ appium-xcode@3.8.0
│ │ ├── @babel/runtime@7.4.4 deduped
│ │ ├── appium-support@2.27.0 deduped
│ │ ├── asyncbox@2.5.2 deduped
│ │ ├── lodash@4.17.11 deduped
│ │ ├── plist@3.0.1 deduped
│ │ ├── semver@6.0.0 deduped
│ │ ├── source-map-support@0.5.12 deduped
│ │ └── teen_process@1.14.1 deduped
│ ├─┬ appium-xcuitest-driver@2.113.2
│ │ ├── @babel/runtime@7.4.4 deduped
│ │ ├── appium-base-driver@3.15.5 deduped
│ │ ├── appium-ios-driver@4.2.3 deduped
│ │ ├── appium-ios-simulator@3.10.0 deduped
│ │ ├── appium-remote-debugger@4.3.0 deduped
│ │ ├── appium-support@2.27.0 deduped
│ │ ├── appium-xcode@3.8.0 deduped
│ │ ├── async-lock@1.2.0 deduped
│ │ ├── asyncbox@2.5.2 deduped
│ │ ├── bluebird@3.5.4 deduped
│ │ ├── js2xmlparser2@0.2.0 deduped
│ │ ├── lodash@4.17.11 deduped
│ │ ├── node-simctl@5.0.1 deduped
│ │ ├── portscanner@2.2.0 deduped
```

Comment: Can you tell which npm library are you using? Is it https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb?

Comment: Gaurav Sharma i have just added the library details in my question

Comment: I was not asking for `npm list`. See my answer, it might help you

Comment: MongoDB version 3.12 seems to be rather old.

Comment: That is the requirement .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For official node.js [MongoDB driver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb). The syntax for projection is like this

```
const cursor =client.db ('snapp_transactions').collection ('price_check_validation').find (
      {
        Scenario: IDs [i]
      }, {
         projection: {
           _id: 0,
           'Ticket Code': 0,
           'Unit Tax Quoted': 1
         }
      }
    );
```

**Edit:** 
Fields that you need set them to 1 and fields that you don't need set them to 0 in the projection object.

Further reading on [projection on find method](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.2/api/Collection.html#find)

Comment: Gaurav Sharma can you tell me how can i include multiple field in the above code ?

Comment: I have updated the answer for multiple fields projection